# ACPI problem with recent kernels

Tags: kernel, acpi

In recent versions of popular Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Fedora, Mint, Debian) I always have to put `acpi=off` into the kernel parameter list before I want to boot the computer. This happens to both the live CDs and the installed version. I have been unable to find information on fixing this. I guess I have to change some settings in the kernel and compile my own (my Gentoo installation doesn't have this problem).

How should I go forward in fixing this ACPI thing?

Update 1: Screenshot
[image]

Update 2: [kernel config diffs](http://pastebin.com/ZtY94Fym) (I grep'ed for ACPI so it's relatively short). If you want, also have a look at [my Gentoo kernel config](http://pastebin.com/uatqVgMq) (working), and [Mint's bundled kernel config](http://pastebin.com/iCUuSXPP) (not working).

Update 3: I used the kernel config of Mint to compile a kernel for Gentoo and got the same error, which is a good sign that the problem is with the kernel config.

Update 4: In my particular case, disabling the "new interface card" in the BIOS eliminates the problem (Security -> I/O Interface Security -> New Interface Card -> Locked -- via http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1662577&p=11851036#post11851036)

Comment: What is the problem that you are getting when you don't set acpi=off?

Comment: Did you try comparing your working kernel config with the problematic ones - with `sdiff` for example?

Comment: @dirk: Not having `acpi=off` results in kernel panics when booting. The last line says something about "registering" and before that is a bunch of text that doesn't make sense to me. Will post the text when I get a chance.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: How do I get the config for the stock kernels of Ubuntu or Mint?

Comment: @phunehehe, in Ubuntu, you'll find the config in `/boot/config-<kernelversion>`.

Comment: For Ubuntu - see cjm's comment, for Mint it is the same: `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Now I found the config, but don't know what to do about it. Do I have to build custom kernels?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends what the actual problem is. Could you paste the diff between the working kernel config and the broken one to someplace like pastebin?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz I added the pastebin.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that somehow. Unfortunately the diff is not much useful because (1) there is no indication, which side is from a working kernel (2) it was not a good idea to just grep it for acpi - don't worry that much about size, full diff is still less then a photo.

Comment: Two more things: is `acpi=off` the only option that works (have you tried different ones)? What are the kernel versions in each case?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Please see my updates. At this point I'm thinking that I'll need a custom kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Generally this is caused by broken acpi bios, however, if you can identify a specific kernel version where it works without acpi=off, and one where it breaks, then you can start bisecting to narrow down exactly what change caused it.  That could lead to finding a kernel bug that would need fixed, or possibly understanding the nature of the bug in your bios, and finding a work around.

Answer (score 2):

Before you go into the hassle of custom-built kernel (which might do you good anyway), you can try some more boot options to either debug the problem or maybe even boot successfully. Here are some that I'd try: `acpi=noirq`, `acpi=strict`, `pci=noacpi`.

One simple trick you might use is to just run your Mint on the Gentoo kernel. To do that, you must copy files from two locations: `/boot/` (where the kernel and initrd reside) and `/lib/modules` (where all the modules of each kernel are kept). The command `uname -r`, run from the working gentoo system, will indicate the appropriate files/directories you will have to copy to your Mint partition.

*If* you end up building your own kernel, mind two things:

1. You cannot just use the kernel configuration from your working gentoo kernel with the sources from Mint (I'm referring to the configs you've pasted) - because they refer to different kernel sources. If you really want the gentoo configuration with Mint kernel, you can try to use the gentoo config file **with the same or newer version** of kernel sources from Mint. Then, you should copy the gentoo config tou your Mint sources directory, naming it `.config` and first of all **run `make oldconfig`** before doing any manual configuration.
2. In case you might run into ACPI problems in the future, make sure to enable ACPI debugging (`CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG` option) and read about using it in `<your_sources_dir>/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt` and other files referenced from there.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding the acpi_osi=Windows (lie) and acpi_backlight=vendor parameters as boot optional. The problem was due to a foxconn motherboard

Comment: my problem was indeed bios related too, see update 4