# Is there any way to get Intel i915 graphics without ACPI?

Tags: linux, acpi, i915

I've got an old tablet PC that panics on boot with ACPI GPE storms. It boots just fine with `acpi=off` in the kernel arguments, however I've never been able to get the Intel i915 accelerated graphics working (Intel 855GM chipset).

I have no idea why the two should be related but I've come across a few reports of `i915` being dependent on `acpi`:

- [The i915 drm module has an indirect dependency on ACPI | Red Hat Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=582708)
- [Why Intel i915 driver depends on button module | Debian User Forums](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=84527)

How can I verify this dependency and is there any way to get accelerated graphics with my busted ACPI?

Comment: This thread also looks related: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1790103.html

Comment: It sounds obvious but writing this question out made it clearer in my mind that I should work harder on getting ACPI to work. This link (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18241/57065) helped me to try pci=noacpi as a kernel argument which allows my computer to boot with acpi and thus i915.

Comment: Great. Glad that you figured out your solution. Make sure to write it up as an answer and mark it accepted so that others know the solution too 8-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to try in this AskUbuntu Q&A titled: [How can I fix broken i915 drivers for Intel GPUs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136593/how-can-i-fix-broken-i915-drivers-for-intel-gpus).

In [researching this issue](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/9/9/163) it would appear the answer is no there isn't a way to enable i915 without ACPI.

*excerpt*

> On Mon, Sep 09, 2013 at 04:42:20PM +0800, Aaron Lu wrote:
>
> > According to Matthew Garrett, "Windows 8 leaves backlight control up
> >     to individual graphics drivers rather than making ACPI calls itself.
> >     There's plenty of evidence to suggest that the Intel driver for
> >     Windows [8] doesn't use the ACPI interface, including the fact that
> >     it's broken on a bunch of machines when the OS claims to support
> >     Windows 8.  The simplest thing to do appears to be to disable the
> >     ACPI backlight interface on these systems".
> >
> > There's a problem with that approach, however, because simply
> >     avoiding to register the ACPI backlight interface if the firmware
> >     calls _OSI for Windows 8 may not work in the following situations:
> >      (1) The ACPI backlight interface actually works on the given system
> >          and the i915 driver is not loaded (e.g. another graphics driver
> >          is used).
> >      (2) The ACPI backlight interface doesn't work on the given system,
> >          but there is a vendor platform driver that will register its
> >          own, equally broken, backlight interface if not prevented from
> >          doing so by the ACPI subsystem.
> >     Therefore we need to allow the ACPI backlight interface to be
> >     registered until the i915 driver is loaded which then will unregister
> >     it if the firmware has called _OSI for Windows 8 (or will register
> >     the ACPI video driver without backlight support if not already
> >     present).

So it would seem that the 2 are linked.